# Avoid accidental execution in comint mode

Tags: emacs, comint-mode

Sometimes when in comint mode the point is anywhere in the buffer and I press `Return` by mistake. This sends the text at point to the underlying process, which can be really dangerous. Often this text contains many lines and, by chance or not, one of them could be a valid command.

Is there any way to tell comint not to execute anything on `Return` except the last input?

Comment: A comment in [`comint.el:comint-get-old-input-default`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/comint.el#L2268) seems to indicate that the behavior you observe is a bug. I suggest that you report it as such using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, it has been a consistent behavior of any inferior mode for years, and that comment seems to be related to the fact that the commented function returns different things when the point is at an input line than when it is at an output one.

Answer (score 2):

The documented way seems to be override `comint-get-old-input` variable with a custom function. Easiest will be something like this:

```
(setq comint-get-old-input (lambda () (end-of-buffer) (comint-get-old-input-default)))
```

It goes to the end of buffer first, and only then calls `coming-get-olt-input-default`, effectively not messing with the previous output. Put it in your `init.el`,  brief testing shows that it works.